# Stopping objekt when reach 200z

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to freeze my cube when it reach 200z. I want to use it for a tutorial level. So the player/cube will stand stil and there can come up a text that explains the game. If you got some idears to do it a better way, ill be open for all of it.

Comment: Does your player object  have a rigidbody component?

Comment: Yes. The player and the ground. The game is a endles runner

Comment: Maybe you can set rigid body's velocity equals 'vector3.zero' or set rigid body's property 'isKinematic' true.

Comment: But how to do it when my cube reach 200 on the z ax

Comment: Check your rigid body's position Z >= 200f in update function ?

Comment: That's a pretty good idear.

Comment: You can steel freeze the z